# Rewrite URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite URL from `http://example.com/file.php?id=test&cat=category` to `http://example.com/file?test&cat=category`
I only achieved to rewrite path `/file.php` to `/file` with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

How to rewrite the rest of URL? And second question: Is it possible to block default URL access so user must use rewrited URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check on the values in a query string you need to use a RewriteCond with the `QUERY_STRING` variable, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([a-z]+)&cat=([a-z]+)$
```

This says that the RewriteRule must only execute if the query string contains a set of consecutive lowercase letters followed by an ampersand, then "cat=" followed by another set of consecutive letters. The capture groups can be used in the next RewriteRule using `%1` and `%2` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php?id=%1&cat=%2 [L]
```

You don't want to use the `QSA` flag because that will append the user's invalid query string to the end of your rewritten URL. You may still want to use the `NC` flag to ignore case in the match pattern, but it's probably best to work with lowercase-only filenames if possible.

Regarding blocking requests to the finalised (.php) path, I can't think of a way to do this, because even the finalised URL has to run through the .htaccess rules, so forbidding access to it would break the redirect.